# module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'patches'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to annotate precentage in horizontal barplot with matplotlib.
The problem is that when I try to add the precentage annotation I get error:

> "module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'patches'

This is how I try to create the chart:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
%matplotlib inline


sns.set(style="whitegrid")
#sns.set_color_codes("Spectral")



plt.figure(2, figsize=(20,15))
the_grid = GridSpec(2, 2)

plt.subplot(the_grid[0, 1],  title='Original Dataset')
sns.barplot(x='count',y='land_cover_specific', data=df, palette='Spectral')
plt.xlabel('Count')
plt.ylabel('Land cover')

total = len(original)
print(total)

for p in plt.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_width()/total)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() + 0.02
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2
        plt.annotate(percentage, (x, y))

plt.show()
```

I get the bar plot but I do not get the annotation due to this error.
[image]

My end goal: to add teh rpecentage of each bar count out of the total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only need to change :

```
sns.barplot(x='count',y='land_cover_specific', data=df, palette='Spectral')
```

to:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x='count',y='land_cover_specific', data=df, palette='Spectral')
```

and

```
for p in plt.patches:
```

to:

```py
for p in ax.patches:
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
%matplotlib inline


sns.set(style="whitegrid")
#sns.set_color_codes("Spectral")



plt.figure(2, figsize=(20,15))
the_grid = GridSpec(2, 2)

plt.subplot(the_grid[0, 1],  title='Original Dataset')
horizontal = sns.barplot(x='count',y='land_cover_specific', data=df, palette='Spectral')
plt.xlabel('Count')
plt.ylabel('Land cover')


total = len(original)
# print(total)

# for p in plt.patches:
#         percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_width()/total)
#         x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() + 0.02
#         y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2
#         plt.annotate(percentage, (x, y))


def auto_label(horizontal_):
    for index, rectangle in enumerate(horizontal_):
        height = rectangle.get_height()
        width = rectangle.get_width()
        y_value = rectangle.get_y()
        # color is an array containing either hex or rgb values
        # each should map to the color of each in your barchart
        plt.text(width + height/2., y_value, "%d" % 100 * width / total, color=color[index])


auto_label(horizontal)
plt.show()
```